# No recibo datos enviados por xhr a express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

estoy empezando con express y quiero enviar una variable al servidor:

```
var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET","http://localhost:300/data",true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange=()=>{if(http.readyState==4){
    alert(http.responseText);
}}
http.send("id=2");
```

> server.js

```
 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();

 const router = express.Router();
 app.post("/data",function(req,res){
      console.log(req.body.id);
 })
 app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/www/"));

 app.listen(300,function(){
     console.log("true")
 })
```

pero al enviar la petición al servidor me lanza error 404. ¿alguien me puede decir porque?

Comment: Tienes que usar body-parser

Comment: Si no sabes como puedo hacerte una respuesta, pero creo que no lo amerita. Mira los ejemplos en el módulo https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples

Comment: uso express en la vercion 4.17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te está dando error 404 porque literalmente la ruta con el método que quieres usar no existe, si te fijas bien, en tu código el endpoint data es utilizado solo por un método post, y en el cliente estás intentando consumir una petición de tipo get.

Sólo debes de cambiar el metodo en el cliente o en el servidor, dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer:

```javascript
// server.js

const express = require("express");
 const app = express();

 const router = express.Router();
// CAMBIO -------------------------------------
 app.get("/data",function(req,res){
      console.log(req.body.id);
 })
 app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/www/"));

 app.listen(300,function(){
     console.log("true")
 })
```

```javascript
client.js

var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET","http://localhost:300/data",true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange=()=>{if(http.readyState==4){
    alert(http.responseText);
}}
http.send("id=2");
```

Como adicional, te comenté hace un rato que debes usar el modulo body-parser para consumir el body de la petición de esa manera.

Solo instálalo y agrégalo:

```javascript
...
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
...
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: A partir de `express v4.16.0` podes usar [`express.urlencoded([options])`](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#express.urlencoded)